# From All Temperatures To One Temperature

Tags: java

How i change this program **"from Convert all Temperatures"** to Convert **"Temperature that i want"**

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Suhu {

    static double suhuawal;
    static double suhuakhir;

    static double CelToFah(double suhuawal) {
        double cf;
        cf = ((suhuawal*1.8)+32);
        return cf;
    }

    static double CelToRem(double suhuawal) {
        double cr;
        cr = (suhuawal*0.8);
        return cr;
    }

    static double CelToKel(double suhuawal) {
        double ck;
        ck = suhuawal+273.15;
        return ck;
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Masukkan suhu awal: ");
        x = in.nextDouble();
        suhuakhir = CelToFah(x);
        System.out.println("Suhu Akhir Fahrenheit: "+suhuakhir);
        suhuakhir = CelToRem(x);
        System.out.println("Suhu Akhir Reamur: "+suhuakhir);
        suhuakhir = CelToKel(x);
        System.out.println("Suhu Akhir Kelvin: "+suhuakhir); 
    }

}
```

Please don't change the Body Structure, Just Add Method or Something Else that Can Help me

Comment: Downvoted: no reasonable attempt provided to indicate you're not just looking for a freebie

Comment: Well Thank you For Commenting

Comment: _Please don't change the Body Structure, Just Add Method or Something Else that Can Help me_ - this is not a 'do my work for me' website. Ask a specific question about something you don't understand rather than just telling us to finish your assignment.

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Suhu {

static double suhuawal;

    static double suhuakhir;

    static double CelToFah(double suhuawal)

    {

    double cf;

    cf = ((suhuawal*1.8)+32);

    return cf;

    }

    static double CelToRem(double suhuawal)

    {

    double cr;

    cr = (suhuawal*0.8);

    return cr;

    }

    static double CelToKel(double suhuawal)

    {

    double ck;

    ck = suhuawal+273.15;

    return ck;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    double x;

               Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
               System.out.print("Please give the value : ");
               x = in.nextDouble();
               int chosen=0;
               double ans=0;
               System.out.print("Choose which one to convert to : ");
        System.out.println("[1] Kelvin: "+suhuakhir); 
        System.out.println("[2] Fahrenheit: "+suhuakhir);
        System.out.println("[3] Reamur: "+suhuakhir);
        chosen=in.nextInt();
        switch (chosen) {
  case 1:
    ans = CelToKel(x);
break;
  case 2:
    ans = CelToFah(x);
    break;
      case 3:
    ans = CelToRem(x);
    break;

  default:
    chosen=-1;
    break;
}
if(-1==chosen)System.out.print("Wrong choice! ");
else
System.out.print("After conversion : "+ans);


    }

}
```